How to choose element from list incrementally to assign to a instance when creation
I would create a instance and assigned a instance with a number X , X belongs to [Red Green Blue Purple]
Question: Find a color from the list incrementally to assign to a instance when creating a new one.
Description:
Choosing color is always the next color that we assigned previously. Eg, If Green was the color assigned previously, then Blue would be the next color to be assigned to next instance.
If one instance was deleted, then its assigned color would be released. eg [Red(assigned) Green(release) Blue(assign) Purple]. But next choosing color should still be purple. Green would be choose till next creation. There are at most 4 instances. We need to delete one if we want to create again
And no duplicated color should be existed when there are 4 instances.

My presudo approach to find a color to assign is as below:
eg. we have this setup
const color = [R G B P]

after we load up data from db: say we already had 

instance A: color =red

instance B: color =green


When creating new instance: 

maxColor = findTheMaxColor(a arrary of instances) [loop arrary to find out the max number]
choosingColor = findChoosingColorThatIsStillAvaliable(maxColor, a arrary of instances) [increment maxColor by 1 and then check if that was used yet, otherwise increment by 1 again til it's still there]

Then we got: 
new instance C's color = color[choosingColor] 

However, may I know if there is a better algorithm or data structure out there for this kind of problem?
------Update------
To further elaborate user interaction:
It's a very basic UI. There will be a button in userinterface for creating a instance.
After creating an instance. UI will display the a newly created instance's color on the screen along with existing instances
eg.
[Create]
Instance A (Red)[delete]
Instance B (Green) [delete]
Instance c (Blue) [delete]  Newly created after clicking the button.
Behind the scene, there will be a logic to maintain the chosen color. This is the part I elaborated above.
ps. [] represents button

If we choose a color and then immediately release it again. Will the next chosen color be the same color or not?

I'll assume it will not be the same color, unless that is the only available color.

Yes, you are correct

You could have a class that maintains the colors and has a boolean for each color that indicates its availability. Also maintain a current index in the array of colors.
An instance will represent one color via its value property.
You can then call one of two methods:

chooseThis: this chooses the current color, and a new instance is returned that represents the next available color (or no color when there is none available). The constructor will check which next color is available, by looking from the current index onwards. If there is none available in that search, then do the same again but starting at index 0. If again there is none, then this means no more colors are available and the new instance will have value equal to undefined.
release: this takes one or more color names as argument and releases those in the new instance that is returned.

Instances are considered immutable, so you can pass them to setState, for instance like this:
Initialisation:
this.state = {
    colors: new Colors(["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Purple"])
};

Choosing the current color:
setState((prevState) => ({ 
   colors: colors.chooseThis()
}))

Releasing one or more colors:
setState((prevState) => ({ 
   colors: colors.release("Purple", "Red")
}))

Rendering the current color:
<span>{this.state.colors.value}</span>

Here is a possible implementation of that class, including a plain JavaScript demo


class Colors {
    #colors;
    #available;
    #currentIndex;
    value;
    
    constructor(colors, available=[], i=0) {
        this.#colors = colors;
        this.#available = colors.map((_, i) => available[i] !== false);
        i = this.#available.indexOf(true, i);
        if (i == -1) i = this.#available.indexOf(true);
        this.#currentIndex = i;
        this.value = colors[i];
    }
    
    chooseThis() {
        if (!this.#available[this.#currentIndex]) throw new Error("this is no longer the current color!");
        return new Colors(this.#colors, Object.assign([...this.#available], {[this.#currentIndex]: false}), (this.#currentIndex + 1) % this.#colors.length);
    }
    
    release(...colors) {
        for (const color of colors) {
            let i = this.#colors.indexOf(color);
            if (i == -1) new Error("unknown color: " + color);
            if (this.#available[i]) throw new Error("color " + color + " was already available");
        }
        return new Colors(this.#colors, this.#available.map((b, i) => b || colors.includes(this.#colors[i])), this.#currentIndex);
    }
}

// Demo
let colors = new Colors(["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Purple"]);
console.log(`Current color is ${colors.value}. Choosing it...`);
colors = colors.chooseThis(); // choose it: get new immutable object
console.log(`Current color is ${colors.value}. Choosing it...`);
colors = colors.chooseThis(); 
console.log(`Current color is ${colors.value}. Choosing it...`);
colors = colors.chooseThis(); 
console.log("Releasing Green");
colors = colors.release("Green");
console.log(`Current color is ${colors.value}. Choosing it...`);
colors = colors.chooseThis(); 
console.log(`Current color is ${colors.value}. Choosing it...`);
colors = colors.chooseThis(); 
console.log("Releasing Blue");
colors = colors.release("Blue");
console.log(`Current color is ${colors.value}. Choosing it...`);
colors = colors.chooseThis(); 
console.log("Releasing Blue and Purple");
colors = colors.release("Blue", "Purple");
console.log(`Current color is ${colors.value}.`);




Thank you for your answer. Sorry I didnt mention it clearly (tagged as react js) . I assume, if you create a class in react project, you mean to put it into a state. The thing is, whenever we update the state(color class), we need to create a new object isnt it? (Technically it still works, but it is not quite the right way to work in react project)
Or, I think we may create a object and init it like your constructor as state. ?

OK, I will delete this answer then. If you want a response that integrates with react, then it will help if you put your requirements of visualisation in your question, because without visualisation constraints, you don't need anything different from what I posted. Add your code, so a reply can integrate with that provided code.

it's ok. If you want, you may delete it. But your answer could still be converted into react version and it is still valid and so far there is only one answer. I would prefer to accept this, if no more answer provided. After all, it's just that it's not in react, but still JavaScript.

OK, I tried to update my answer. Let me know if this is usable.

Thanksss...its so great... Just a question, if I call setState, would it cause the components rerender ? (just wonder if it re-render, then it seems to a performance issue)

Well, that's the purpose of setState. If you have nothing rendered that is related to the change in color, then you shouldn't use setState for managing the instances of this class, but just use plain variables. If on the other hand, there is something visualised that relates to the current color, then you should render, right?

I was just thinking... actually the purpose of the class object is to maintain what color should be selected next time creating instance... Im thinking if everytime I create a instance, I would also show the color of it. Then I use useState to update color object and causing a rerender wont be a issue cuz I need to update the screen to show the new instance color anyway.
But in theory, color state has nothing to do with what screen is showing, Screen is showing instance's color only. So, I am just struggling if this approach still sounds

I'm rereading what you wrote here, but I don't understand it. It would be good if you would edit your question and give a few concrete examples of what you expect to show and how the interaction would work and the feedback from the system.

Thank you for your effort and dedication in this question
When create a instance, we rely on  "colors state" to choose the color for instance. And then we update state of color to keep information sync with in the state. And this action, updating the state would cause a re-render, which is not necessary because the view doesn't display "object colors" at all. So, my question is, is it still a good approach to maintain colors by state

Like I wrote above, if you don't display anything about object colors, then you should not manage it with setState, but plain variables. But I don't know what "choose the color" is. Is that a reference to the method, or to some user interaction. I see you have no updated the question? I would really suggest you explain the user interaction (without reference to state, but just to understand the use case) inside the question.

I have updated user interaction part for use case. See if this helps. I am still thinking how plain variables could maintain this case while state is not a good choice.

Only last question, how do you prevent memery leak here. When you return an new instance and assign it to variable... the old instance is leaked

The old instance is not leaked. It is marked for garbage collection.

May I ask usually how long will it last until it got cleaned? I looked for this and usually answers online only showed that it would be garbage collected at some point.
